What feature breaks recursion
In my VSIX extension I created a DialogWindow-based dialog which contains 2 editable ComboBoxes:
dialog.xaml
<ComboBox Name="HeaderFilter" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="HeaderFilterChangedEventHandler" IsEditable="True"/>
<ComboBox Name="ImplementationFilter" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ImplementationFilterChangedEventHandler" IsEditable="True"/>

dialog.cs:
public partial class Dialog : DialogWindow
{
    private void HeaderFilterChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImplementationFilter.Text += "1";
    }

    private void ImplementationFilterChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HeaderFilter.Text += "2";
    }
}


And I had found that typing in either of these controls doesn't cause an infinite recursion. For example, typing a single symbol in HeaderFilter causes the following call trace:
HeaderFilterChangedEventHandler()
ImplementationFilterChangedEventHandler()
stop at next HeaderFilterChangedEventHandler call

Which C# feature stops the recursion and when can I rely on it?

If you look at Microsoft's implementation
you'll find this:
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(
                  "Text", // Property name
                  typeof(string), // Property type
                  typeof(TextBox), // Property owner
                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( // Property metadata
                          string.Empty, // default value
                          FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | // Flags
                              FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                          new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextPropertyChanged),    // property changed callback
                          new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceText),
                          true, // IsAnimationProhibited
                          UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus   // DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger
                          ));

UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus means that the binding source will be updated (and the change event triggered) when the TextBox loses focus, rather than immediately when the text changes. This breaks recursion in this case.
I'm not aware of a strong guarantee that this behavior will persist in future versions or alternative implementations. Indeed, the TextBox documentation implies the change event will fire whenever the value changes.
To be certain that your event handler will not trigger recursion in a more complex scenario or if future WPF versions have different behavior, you can expressly handle that case like this:
private bool _isHandlingEvent = false;

private void HeaderFilterChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_isHandlingEvent) return;

    try
    {
        _isHandlingEvent = true;
        ImplementationFilter.Text += "1";
    }
    finally
    {
        _isHandlingEvent = false;
    }
}

